# Tick data backtesting Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Can I backtest the strategy like if this same bar that is opened right now volume is above my added value then it will make a buy-stop entry from previous bars high? It can make it by using real-time bar and use tick data and running this on a live chart but I want to know how can I backtest this thing. Right now backtest using when the bar is closed but this is not showing the real results. Maybe is there any repaint functions or something to try this to backtest (is it even possible in pinescript)?

I am tried to google this problem also but didn't find the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, tick data is not available on historical bars. Only the OHLC.

See [broker emulator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#broker-emulator) and [bar magnifier](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#bar-magnifier).